# Is it possible to get all mine groups (user=me) by graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

My need is to fetch all the groups that i have joined using facebook graph api. Is it even possible? When i use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=groups
```

with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ (i got all possible permissions for login token) i'm getting only groups that hich I manage (i'm admin of it), but i need to get all my groups, to which I belong. I do not get an empty return, so I assume my error is due to a faulty syntax...

Is it even possible? Both, in the reviewed FB API documentation and in various topics here I have not found an explanation why I only get such (admin) groups, but maybe something I do not understand, or missing? It's a bit unclear for me.

I will be grateful for every hint! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get ALL groups anymore, only those you manage. The required permission `user_groups` is deprecated and got replaced by `user_managed_groups`.

You are not missing anything, it is just not possible anymore.

Comment: Well, t's really bad. :( But thank you very much for the information.

Of course, I already have a few ideas to work around this problem. First one is use information from my timeline. Other one is use https://web.facebook.com/bookmarks/groups and parse html information. What do You think about it?

Comment: scraping/parsing is not allowed. don´t do that. rule of thumb: if it´s not possible with the api, it is most likely not allowed.

Comment: Thank You again for information. It's a bit strange, cause i still can take it manually, for example adding my groups id to program. What are consequences when i will make simple database with my groups id?

Comment: that is something you would have to ask facebook directly ;)